# Reading multiple data files with a loop on Python

Tags: python, import

Hi I have a over 200 data files with name similar names like abc.20.0000.catalog.out , abc.20.1000.catalog.out, abc.20.2000.catalog.out ...... abc.40.0000.catalog.out

Each file contains data like this

```
   Group catalog for redshift  18.1000
 1) group ID
 2) group mass (Msun/h)
 3- 5) initial position (Mpc/h)
 6- 8) final position (Mpc/h)
 9-11) velocity (km/s)
 12) number of particles  

250103187  0.227591E+08 1.86  1.03  2.51  1.65  1.06  2.53  -47.56  7.50  3.83    328
202456030  0.167918E+08 0.29  4.57  2.02  0.23  4.63  2.14  -13.27  10.67 3.68    242
89479147  0.763262E+06  1.47  4.80  0.89  1.34  4.83  0.99  -28.90  6.20  17.30    11
```

each such file contains over 10^6 lines.

I want to do the following:
1. I want to read the data from each file and erase the text on top. 
2. I want to then store the data from all these files into a single big list of   matrices, each matrix being the data from each of these files.

Comment: Why don't you show what you have done? The question is also very unclear.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Python/Pandas solution:

```
import pandas as pd
import glob

L = []
for f in glob.glob('abc*'):       
   df = pd.read_csv(f,skiprows=1)
   L.append(df.values)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Here's part 1:**

A particularly useful piece of code is: `'abc.{0}000.catalog.out'.format(someString)`. The `{0}` acts as a placeholder for whatever the `someString` is. So to read in all your files, and erase the top text, you might have:

```
for i in range(200, 401):
    file_name = 'abc.{0}000.catalog.out'.format(str(i)[:2] + '.' + str(i)[2:])

    with open(file_name) as file:
        wanted_lines = file.readlines()
    with open(file_name, 'w+') as file:
         string = ''
         for lines in wanted_lines[8:]:
             string += lines
         file.write(string)
```

> I want to then store the data from all these files into a single big list of matrices, each matrix being the data from each of these files.

- You're going to have to clarify or give an example of what you're talking about.